# Issues importing pandas tool scatter_matrix

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

I am currently facing an import issue with `pandas.tools.plotting`. I try to import the scatter matrix via

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

But I get the following error message from visual studio code:

> [pylint] E0611:No name 'scatter_matrix' in module
> 'pandas.tools.plotting'

I also tried

```
from pandas.tools import scatter_matrix
```

but it didn't work either. Why can't I import the scatter matrix?

I am using

- python 3.6.4
- pandas 0.22.0

Answer (score 5):

You need to use this line of code to import pandas scatter_matrix. As seen in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-matrix-plot) of pandas visualization.

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

e.g.
scatter = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(X, c = y, marker = 'o', s=40, hist_kwds={'bins':15}, figsize=(9,9), cmap = cmap)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).